# Railo REST component has no access to application variables

Tags: rest, cfc, railo

I've been playing with the REST functionality in Railo 4, with limited success...

I have two paths set up, the first works exactly as I'd expect but requests to the second seem to exist outside of the application...

I have two mappings:
`/api` and `/admin/api`

I created `/admin/api` first, I'm not sure if that makes a difference, but everything is working fine there and not in `/api`.

I have the following components in both:

```
<cffunction
    name="test"
    access="remote"
    returntype="struct"
    returnformat="json"
    output="true"
    httpmethod="GET"
    >

    <cfscript>
        return Application;
    </cfscript>

</cffunction>
```

In my application I have a bunch of variables that are created `onApplicationStart` - if I run this component from `/admin/api` they are all available to me, however running the exact same component from `/api` I don't have any!

I set up the `/admin/api` a while ago and have had it functioning with no problems - I'm wondering if I've missed a step when I set up `/api`...
Can anyone explain why I would have access to the application variables in one path, but not in the other?

Comment: Where is the `Application.cfc` file in relation to your physical directories?

Comment: The Application.cfc is in the web root. I'm setting up the rest mappings manually in Railo admin.
After a fair bit of messing about, I've found that it works fine as long as the CFCs are located at least 2 folders deep anywhere in the filestructure! 
AJ has been doing some testing with me and managed to get it working mostly as expected, but I can't figure out what causes the issue.